# Tag input too low when editing on Meta Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design, meta

When editing a question on Meta Stack Exchange, the input field for the tags is too low. Or the tags are styled with a too large margin-top.

[image]

Comment: An exact dupe - but I missed it because of the title. Suggest this Q is closed as dupe, but kept non-deleted.

Comment: Posts closed as dupes are not deleted normally, exactly *because* they can act as signposts.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that revealed another bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230000/bad-line-break-of-close-link-when-theres-an-edit :-)